# Angular ChangeDetection do not display right data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I met a situation that i can't solve. 
My project is using angular 6.
I have a form displayed like a table using ngFor and i made possible to add rows in the table.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Prestations</th>
            <th>Unité</th>
            <th>Prix</th>
            <th>Pourcentage Promotionnel</th>
            <th>Activez la promotion?</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let prestation of listPrestations">
            <td class="centering">
                <strong>
                    {{ prestation.prestation.label }}
                </strong>
            </td>
            <td class="centering">
                <strong>
                    {{ prestation.prestation.unite || 'Non défini' }}
                </strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group" required>
                    <input type="number" step=0.1 [(ngModel)]="prestation.pricePerUnit" id="prestation-pricePerUnit-{{prestation.prestation.id}}" name="pricePerUnit" class="input-field righting" min=0 placeholder="Prix unitaire" required>
                    <label class="input-label" for="pricePerUnit">Prix unitaire</label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="number" step=1 [(ngModel)]="prestation.promoPercentage" id="prestation-promoPercentage-{{prestation.prestation.id}}" name="promoPercentage" min=0 max=99 class="input-field righting" placeholder="Pourcentage Promotionnel">
                    <label class="input-label" for="promoPercentage">Pourcentage Promotion</label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="centering">
                <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="prestation.promoActivated" id="prestation-promoActivated-{{prestation.prestation.id}}" name="promoActivated" class="" placeholder="">
            </td>
            <td class="centering">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deletePrestation(prestation.prestation.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

which gave something like that [image: Picture before click on Ambulance]

but when i add a row in my array

```
add(prestationId: number) {
    var x: ICompanyPrestation[] = [];
    this.tmpPrestation = new CompanyPrestation();
    this.tmpPrestation.company = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.company));
    this.tmpPrestation.prestation = this.prestations.find(prestation => prestation.id == prestationId);
    if (!this.listPrestations.find(prestation => prestation.prestation.id == prestationId)) {
        this.listPrestations.push(this.tmpPrestation);
    } else {
        this.isAlreadyIn();
    }
}
```

i can see that the array contains right datas but seems like original inputs are displayed as 0 "pricePerUnits" in the array or "Prix" on the screen

.
[image: console.log of array after click on "ambulance"]

It's like changeDetection don't work.

[image: Screen after click on "ambulance"]

Does someone know what goes wrong in what i am doing?!

Thanks

Comment: what is the changeDetectionStrategy of your components? Default of onPush?

Comment: It is Default! But i tried to force the ChangeDetection to work with detectChange but no results

Answer (score 0):

Angular isn't using the correct tracking to get the data.

Add a custom tracking function.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let prestation of listPrestations; trackBy: customTB">
```

```js
customTB(item, index) {
  return `${index}-${item.id}`;
}
```

Comment: I tried that too. But i keep getting the same results

Comment: Oh excuse me but i don't really get what you mean by minimal complete and virifiable example

Comment: I mean something that reproduces the issue, usually done with stackblitz.

Comment: why your account is suspended?

Comment: @Sajeetharan sorry for the delay, you imagine why I took so much time :) I caved in and [fed the troll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500060/how-to-create-reference-to-a-dynamically-created-component/53500118?noredirect=1#comment93873181_53500118). he was smart enough to delete his messages and don't get suspended, but I wasn't. Anyway, I taught me a lesson I had forgotten, so I guess I should be thankful !

Answer (score 0):

You can manully start the change detection by calling the `detectChages`

```
add(prestationId: number) {
    var x: ICompanyPrestation[] = [];
    this.tmpPrestation = new CompanyPrestation();
    this.tmpPrestation.company = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.company));
    this.tmpPrestation.prestation = this.prestations.find(prestation => prestation.id == prestationId);
    if (!this.listPrestations.find(prestation => prestation.prestation.id == prestationId)) {
        this.listPrestations.push(this.tmpPrestation);
    } else {
        this.isAlreadyIn();
    }


    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();

}
```

Also inject it in the constructor

```
constructor(
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,
) {
```

Comment: do u have `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,` in the component

Comment: Hum i did'nt have it. For the detectChange to work, is it required?

Comment: NO. having it might cause the change detection to not update the values.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out!

Seems there was error in my naming convention about "id", "name", etc and that was enough to create the error.

Thanks