# How to create reference to a dynamically created component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't find anywhere how to create reference to a component that I create dynamically from array?

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <my-component [data]="item.data"></my-component>
</div>
```

I need to have access to every `<my-component>` (which will be created dynamically from the array) in the TypeScript code

**Example:**

The `length` of `items` array is 2. So then in TypeScript code I need to have something like this.

myComponent0 - reference to the 1. `<my-component>`

myComponent1 - reference to the 2. `<my-component>`

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [**`ViewChildren`**](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

```
import { ViewChildren, QueryList, ... } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChildren(MyComponent) components: QueryList<MyComponent>

  ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.components.forEach(componentInstance => console.log(componentInstance));
  }

  ...

}
```

Here `MyComponent` is the exported name of the Component Class. This is generally of type `QueryList` so you can essentially treat it as an array and do the needful.

This will only be available after the `AfterViewInit` hook of the Component.

---

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-view-children-eg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: thanks, working like I wanted. Until today i knew only about ViewChild and didn't know about the ViewChildren,

Answer (score 4):

Use the view children decorator.

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <my-component [data]="item.data" #components></my-component>
</div>
```

```js
@ViewChildren('components') components: QueryList<MyComponent>;
```

Comment: @Ploppy and in the Typescript, it will reference all components. Seeing that it does more than the other answer, please redirect me to the source of your statement `this NOT the recommended approach` !

Comment: Who in hell would want a variable which value changes depending on where you access it???

Comment: People that make `click` events on the component (for instance) ? Seeing that you didn't provide any source for your statement, I can only assume that you made it from your own opinion. While you have the right to provide it, I am going to ask you that in the future, you don't consider your opinion as a general guidance, but as what it is, in order to not induce people in error. Thank you in advance !

Comment: I don't see the point of your stackblitz, but thank you I guess ?

Comment: Others will understand. What you are doing is NOT the right approach and people already showed their opinion (not just me) by upvoting the proper answer. And [this](https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e) is just one of the many online tutorials related to component query. And I will say it again NO programmer (expect you) would want a variable which value depends on where you access it, that's complete nonsense.

Comment: @Ploppy (and while we're at it, I enforce you to stop talking for other programmers. We aren't sharing a single consciousness and you certainly don't represent anyone but yourself. So, speak your mind but keep your opinions to yourself).

Comment: Nowhere it is written but the angular community teach each others to do it this way but yours is the right one, damn, that's one way to think. So let's recapitulate, basically the only argument you gave us is: 'I did not answer the question properly but it works and does something the OP didn't ask for, so I'm happy'. Well guess what? Just because it works doesn't mean it's the right way to do it. So keep being negative and childish. A responsible person would at least edit his question, but it seems your ego is to big. Have a great day.

Comment: Funny how it goes from "it's not the recommended approach" to "we don't teach that between each other" (which again, is your own opinion). The argument is "I answered the question, it works, and does more than asked. Some random, unskilled guy made a false allegation about this answer, and could not prove it." I won't edit my question, and until you prove me this is **wrong** (opposed to *@Ploppy doesn't like it, so every programmer doesn't like it*), I won't back up, because you can't even provide a simple URL. And my ego is fine, thank you for asking.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ctnjtc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html shows how much you are not understanding the problem. I really hope for you that you are trolling right now. Contact me again when you understand the 3 liner I gave you.

Comment: My stackblitz shows **why** this approach is better, why a particular use-case and a practicle example. Your stackblitz shows nothing but a loop and a click function. Tell me again what is it that I can't understand that you magically explained without any actual explanation, you bafoon. I am seriously tired of you, I already told you goodbye, but now I'm sticking to it. Good luck in your life with that attitude, you're really going to need it.

Comment: The Stackblitz shows that the `components` variable points at 2 different objects depending on where you access it, and that it can be ambiguous, that angular itself has to choose which object to access. The problem is not about who is right, the problem is that you are not even trying to understand. If you want to quit this conversation so much, just do it, no one hold you back.